# Хранение состояния объекта

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api

Пишу сайт с использованием *Laravel* и [*Instagram-API*](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API), и возник такой вопрос.

Когда пользователь переходит в первый раз на страницу `site.com/instagram`, мы у него запрашиваем логин и пароль от аккаунта Инстаграмма.

По этим данным создается объект:

```
$inst = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($login,$password);
```

Но когда, мы хотим перейти по маршруту, например `site.com/instagram/followers`, 
состояние объекта `$inst` сбрасывается.

Собственно, вопрос: **как хранить данный объект (экземпляр), чтобы можно было в любой момент обратиться к нему, не вбивая каждый раз логин и пароль?**

Comment: а почему не используете официальное API? может я не права, но передача логина и пароля в чистом виде как-то не безопасно

Comment: Поддерживаю @apelsinka223 - вы должны работать через токен, а его уже хранить в БД или кэше